# Validate data before insertion in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app which uses user contributed content.
The contribution by each user should be available to all others in real time.
I was looking into [firebase Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database/) for this.
However, when a user contributes content, there are quite heavy validations and calculations (read server side) to be done on the data before making it available to others.
Is it possible to have a server side validation in firebase ? Or should I look for alternatives ?

Comment: Although the cloud functions could be useful, I recommend the database rules. It is much quicker and safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, Firebase did not have a feature to implement server-side processing/calculations. All your processing had to be done on the client side.

Now, they've recently introduced a new feature called [Cloud Functions For Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Its a really useful new addition where you can write server-side code without the hassles of managing servers or instances. Read up more about it from the above link.

Also, [this Youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM) by Jen Person is a great start. And, you can find examples similar to your use case [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples).